# Alternative implementation for creating a dictionary using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a snippet as follow. Basically I would like to create a dictionary from the series I currently have. If I did it the long way, there was no problem, the code run fine and I got the expected results.

```
class Program
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> series = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4 };
        Dictionary<int, List<int>> D = new Dictionary<int,List<int>>();
        foreach (var item in series)
        {
            D.Add(item, seriesWithinSeries(item));
        }

    }
     public static List<int> seriesWithinSeries(int seed)
     {
         return Enumerable.Range(0, seed).Where(x => x < seed).ToList();
     }
}
```

How do I convert that into Linq? I have tried this:

```
D = series.Select(x=> { return new (x,seriesWithinSeries(x));}).ToDictionary<int,List<int>>();
```

But the compiler complaints I need a type for the new, which makes sense. However, I do not really know how to fix it. Please help.

Comment: var d = series.ToDictionary(item => item, item => SeriesWithinSeries(item));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't have a parameterless version. You probably want this:

```
var result = series.ToDictionary(x => x, x => seriesWithingSeries(x));
```

So anonymous type is not needed here. But for the sake of a complete explanation here is a correct syntax with an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx):

```
var result = series
    .Select(x => new { Key = x, Value = seriesWithinSeries(x) })
    .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

Comment: @user1205746 For the record, your error wasn't really related to LINQ at all; it was a problem with the syntax for creating an anonymous type, which is entirely separate from LINQ, even if they are often used together.

Comment: @user1205746 If you really want the data inside to be sorted then you need [`SortedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If you want just access it in a sorted way then `result.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key)` will do what you say.

Comment: Thanks again BartoszKP. I found SortedDictionary and that's why I removed my follow up question but I did not know that we can also OrderByDescending by x.Key... Thank you, so much!! I do not really need SortedDictionary but thought this was the only way to sort...turned out it was overkill for me